# How does C3js decide the y axis range

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm working with C3.js to build graphs for my JSON data. However, I do not understand what decides the Y-axis ranges on the graph. I have a common code to generate 2 bar charts, out of which one comes as expected whereas the other one has high range for Y-axis causing my data bar being diminished. Please take a look at the image below.

[image]

The bar chart on the left has data value equal to 1, yet the axis ranges to 35. A similar graph on the right adjust well.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As yo can read in the doc there is a parameter to set the Y [max](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-y-max) and [min](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-y-min). So you can set the max value dynamically. Or you can set de [Y.padding](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-y-padding) to be 0, so the Y axis will be shorter.

C3.js calculate the Y axis hight dynamically, and I think that have a min default hight.

Comment: I identified the problem.. While reading through c3js code i found that the code was looping on the groups array.. The groups array that i was passing had repeating values.. Fixing the array resolved my problem